# A problem with numbering the problem part of my book in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I want that the Problem's part of my book be considered at the table of content but I don't want it be numbered in my main text as a section . 
How can I Handle it ?

```
\dodumentclass{book}
\begin{document}‎

‎\maketitle‎
\tableofcontents‎
‎\listoffigures‎ 
\listoftables‎  
        ‎
\section{problem}
\end{document}‎
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your chapters end with a "Problems" section, the best is to define a macro to do the job in a consistent way:

```
\newcommand{\problems}{%
  \section*{Problems}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Problems}}
```

Then you'll simply say

```
\problems

<Here the list of problems>
```

The key is the `\addcontentsline`, that adds the entry to the table of contents. You might need to add something to adjust the headers, if you use them.